# displaying custom fieldsets field using method in admin django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have got this model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email"),max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("UserProfile")
    verbose_name_plural = _("UserProfiles")

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

It refers to User using OneToOneField. Now i would like to customize admin.model to display several fields like: user, its first_name from User. So here is Admin.model:

```
@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

list_display = ['user', 'user_firstname', 'email']
readonly_fields = ('user',)

fieldsets = (
    ("User", {
        "fields": (
            'user', 
            'user_firstname, # <- Why not working?
        ),
    }),
    ("Additional info", {
        "fields": (
            'email',

        ),
    })
)

def user_firstname(self,obj):
    return obj.user.first_name
```

`def user_firstname(self,obj)` properly displays user.first_name from base User model however, if i use this method in fieldsets it shows me an error. 
Why i cant refer to this method in fieldsets to display this field and what is the solution?

Comment: Try remove `'` at the start of `'user_firstname`

Comment: it gets an error:   

`sequence item 0: expected str instance, function found`

Answer (score 4):

It seems i have got solution:

Django needs to tread this field as `readonly` to display it inside `fieldsets and fields`, thats why, its nessesary to place this method inside `readonly_fields`:

```
readonly_fields = ('user', 'user_firstname')

def user_firstname(self,obj):
    return obj.user.first_name
```

and secondly, place as a field inside `fieldsets` or `fields`:

```
fieldsets = (
    ("User", {
        "fields": (
            'user',
            'user_firstname', 
        ),
    }),
    ("Additional info", {
        "fields": (
            'email',  
        ),
    })
)
```